# R, Sum frequency data frame by name

Tags: r, sum, dataframe

i have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
      Name         freq         
1   species1        4              
2   species2        8              
3   species1        7              
4   species1        10             
5   species2        9
```

I want to sum the frequency for each species name.
Expected result:

```
      Name             freq
1    species1           21
2    species2           17
```

Comment: you can use the base R function `aggregate`, the `ddply` function from the `plyr` package or, my favorite, `data.table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you attached your data.frame, just do this

```
tapply(freq, INDEX=list(Name),FUN=sum)
```

or, for a data frame called "dataX"

```
tapply(dataX$freq, INDEX=list(dataX$Name),FUN=sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

To develop the `plyr` alternative:

```
ddply(data,~Name,summarise,freqsum=sum(freq))
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a solution using `data.table`.

```
> library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(X)
> DT[, sum(freq), by=Name]
       Name V1
1: species1 21
2: species2 17
```

*where `X` is your original `data.frame`*

If you'd like to label the new column, wrap in `list`:

```
> DT[, list(fsum=sum(freq)), by=Name]
       Name fsum
1: species1   21
2: species2   17
```